# Cannot scrol down and scrape a Dynamic wep page

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape news from the Skynews website which has a dynamic scrolling page (The link for the website I am trying to scrap: https://www.skynewsarabia.com/live-story/1345832-%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%83%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%AB-%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85).

I am using Selenium to scroll down the page and beautifulsoup to scrape information.

The problem is my code is only returning the first five news and it does not perform the scrolling, However, the same code works well on other website and scrolling down the page.

Following is the code I am using to scroll the site and scrap info:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import time
url="https://www.skynewsarabia.com/live-story/1345832-%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%83%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%AB-%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Acoe\Documents\yaman\Scraping\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.skynewsarabia.com/live-story/1345832-%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%83%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%AB-%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85')
time. sleep(3)
previous_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
while True:

    #### the below code to scroll down the web page
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

    time.sleep(3)
    new_height= driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
  # we use "+ str(i+1)" to loop over all we pages in this address because its
  # the same page address including page number in the end

    ## Start the scraping 
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    headlines = soup.find('body').find_all('h2')

    for x in headlines:
        if len(x.text.strip()) > 20:
            fake_news.append(x.text.strip())
            print(x.text.strip())
    else:
        pass
    if new_height == previous_height:
        break
    previous_height = new_height
```

Anyone have any clue why the code could not scroll down this website specifically since the code is doing well for any other website with the same properties? (ex: https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=covid19)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the page is that it will not load new articles when the scroll is 100% to the bottom. You can solve this by incrementing the scroll coordinates by a little every time, instead of going to the bottom of the page.

```py
scrolled = 500
while True:
    driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo(0, {scrolled});')
    scrolled += 500
    time.sleep(1)
```